# error while creating r knitr pdf in my native language

Tags: r, pdf, knitr

I am creating a pdf file using `knitr`. The title and some of other content like graph labels  are in my native language, tamil. However, when knitting I get a font related error. When I try to generate an html or word file using knitr, everything works

```
---
title: "மணிநேர செயல்திறன் ஒப்பீடு"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_height: 9.5
    fig_width: 11
---
```

I tried to add package support for my language, but it didn't solve the problem.

[image]